# Getting files to be committed code problems

Tags: c#, winforms, sharpsvn

BACKGROUND:
What I am trying to do is output a list of files which are unversioned or have had changes done to them and need to be commited.

WHAT IVE TRIED:
I am currently using the code below, the code runs but nothing is outputted to the console. The catch method isnt activated either as the message box doesnt appear.

```
using (SvnClient client = new SvnClient())
{
    try
    {
        EventHandler<SvnStatusEventArgs> statusHandler = new EventHandler<SvnStatusEventArgs>(HandleStatusEvent);
        client.Status(Properties.Settings.Default.LocalFolderPath + @"\" + project, statusHandler);
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
    }
}


private void HandleStatusEvent(object sender, SvnStatusEventArgs args)
{
    switch (args.LocalContentStatus)
    {
        case SvnStatus.NotVersioned: // Handle appropriately
            Console.WriteLine(args.ChangeList);
            break;
    }

    // review other properties of 'args'
}
```

Im not quite sure if this is the right code to get the list of files which need to be committed as the documentation is poor. Ive looked on this site and have found a few other methods (similar to this way) but I still cant get it working. can anyone help?

Comment: @NathanTuggy that link states the method which im using but doesnt explain why im not getting any output. Thats what I need help with, what have I done wrong which means I dont get my desired output.

Comment: Using the value .LocalNodeStatus instead of .LocalContentStatus will probably provide more value.

Comment: thanks @abatishchev for marking my post a duplicate! But how is it a duplicate when im asking for help on my code? does the duplicate tell me what ive got wrong.... NO. Ive looked at the other thread and im using the components from it and still havent got an output, hence why ive tried to code it and want help in finding why theres no output. Do you actually read posts or just go around marking stuff as duplicate for fun?

Comment: Hey, it was a vote to close it, I agreed. Don't take it to heart. It's opened and upvoted. Sorry about this. 98% of duplicates are real duplicates (people don't care to google even once).